# Syncing GPU/non-GPU CSS transitions in Safari

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Two elements in the layout elements animate concurrently via CSS transitions with the same duration and easing. The sidebar slides in (off-canvas navigation), and the main content changes it's width accordingly.

When the sidebar transition is hardware accelerated and the main content is not, e.g.:

```
.sidebar {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.main-content {
  transition: margin 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

the transitions are significantly out of sync in **MacOs Safari 10.0.3** (almost perfect in other browser on MacOs), which is not the case when using non-hardware-accelerated property on the `.sidebar` (`margin`, `left`/`right`, `width`).

Here's a working example with both versions:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJjJPd

I'm looking for a way to sync two transitions when they have exact same timing parameters, but only one of them is hardware-accelerated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @chazsolo Transitions are out of sync in Firefox/Safari despite having the same timing. The question would be: how to make them sync?

Comment: Which version of firefox/safari? Which OS? (In firefox 52 on win I get same results as in chrome). Can you provide a screen capture of the problem?

Comment: Not sure that's something you can do with CSS - that's on the level of  improving/optimizing browser painting, compositing, etc.

Comment: @Dekel Updated the question. I had an older version of Firefox, latest version is just fine, so it narrows down to MacOs Safari I guess.

Comment: Tweaking css timings to make it sync on one machine will make it out of sync for another machine with different hardware. I think your best option is to use JavaScript for transitions if timing is mission critical.

Comment: @Bango The goal is to not use JS, using `transform` even on just one element significantly boosts the FPS.

Comment: From my mind, your options split there. Either take the hardware boosted effects for what they are, or take hardware acceleration out of the picture if it conflicts with your goals. I can't think of an answer to your question where you have hardware acceleration that doesn't do its job to improve performance.

Comment: @Bango Thank you for your time. What I describe here seems to be a browser-specific edge case bug, and I'm looking for a workaround in order for hardware acceleration to do its job and improve performance, hoping that someone is actually familiar with the issue or might understand what's causing it.